# Access Private UIKit Function Without Using Bridging Header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uikit, iphone-privateapi

Consider the private C function [`_UICreateScreenUIImage`](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/UIImage#UICreateScreenUIImage), which returns a `UIImage` snapshot of the current device screen:

```
OBJC_EXTERN UIImage *_UICreateScreenUIImage(void) NS_RETURNS_RETAINED;
```

I can put this in a bridging header and access it in Swift like so:

MyApp-Bridging-Header.h

```
@import UIKit;
UIImage *_UICreateScreenUIImage(void) NS_RETURNS_RETAINED;
```

MyClass.swift

```
let image = _UICreateScreenUIImage()
print(image) // <UIImage: 0x7fc4ba6081c0>, {375, 667}
```

Is there a way I can access `_UICreateScreenUIImage` in pure Swift without using a bridging header?

An initial thought was to create an extension on `UIImage`, but the extension is expecting me to declare the body of the function in the extension:

```
extension UIImage {
    public func _UICreateScreenUIImage(_: Void) -> UIImage // "Expected '{' in body of function declaration"
}
```

This implementation is flawed anyways, as `_UICreateScreenUIImage` isn't a method on `UIImage`.

Is exposing and accessing this method possible in pure Swift?

---

People seem to be confusing my question with "How do I take a screenshot?"  That's not what I'm asking.  I'm asking how do I access methods like `UIImage *_UICreateScreenUIImage(void);` in Swift.  It could be any private method, such as `+(UIImage *)_deviceSpecificImageNamed:(NSString *)name inBundle:(NSBundle *)bundle;` or `+(UIImage *)_pu_PhotosUIImageNamed:(NSString *)name;`
.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a lot easier than you would expect:

```
@asmname("_UICreateScreenUIImage")
func _UICreateScreenUIImage() -> UIImage

// That's it – go ahead and call it:
_UICreateScreenUIImage()
```

As it happens, `@asmname` has actually *just* been changed in the 2.3 builds to `@_silgen_name`, so be ready to adjust accordingly:

```
@_silgen_name("_UICreateScreenUIImage")
func _UICreateScreenUIImage() -> UIImage
```

To my knowledge, `@_silgen_name` does not provide resolution of Objective-C methods. For this, there is the evenmore powerful Objective-C runtime API:

```
let invokeImageNamed: (String, NSTimeInterval) -> UIImage? = {
    // The Objective-C selector for the method.
    let selector: Selector = "animatedImageNamed:duration:"
    guard case let method = class_getClassMethod(UIImage.self, selector)
        where method != nil else { fatalError("Failed to look up \(selector)") }

    // Recreation of the method's implementation function.
    typealias Prototype = @convention(c) (AnyClass, Selector, NSString, NSTimeInterval) -> UIImage?
    let opaqueIMP = method_getImplementation(method)
    let function = unsafeBitCast(opaqueIMP, Prototype.self)

    // Capture the implemenation data in a closure that can be invoked at any time.
    return { name, interval in function(UIImage.self, selector, name, interval) }
}()

extension UIImage {
    // Convenience method for calling the closure from the class.
    class func imageNamed(name: String, interval: NSTimeInterval) -> UIImage? {
        return invokeImageNamed(name, interval)
    }
}

UIImage.imageNamed("test", interval: 0)
```

As far as handling `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED`, this won't be generated for you. Instead, you can use a return type of `Unmanaged`, and wrap that in a function to your convenience:

```
@_silgen_name("_UICreateScreenUIImage")
func _UICreateScreenUIImage() -> Unmanaged<UIImage>
func UICreateScreenUIImage() -> UIImage {
    return _UICreateScreenUIImage().takeRetainedValue()
}
```

Comment: This works!  Amazing!  Where are `asmname` and `_silgen_name` documented?  Is this the equivalent of `extern C` in Swift?

Comment: To my knowledge is not documented (outside of LLVM's internals I'm sure). The term `asmname` would indicate that it is indeed equivalent to `extern` in that it simply instructs the assembler to seek out the symbol elsewhere. `_silgen_name` would more specifically mean that it produces `builtin ""()` declarations during SIL generation (which in turn are resolved by the assembler similar to `extern`).

Comment: Thank you very much!  I expect to mark this as accepted and award the bounty to you.  Another followup question: What if I wanted to access a private class method on `UIImage` itself, such as: `+(UIImage *)_pu_PhotosUIImageNamed:(NSString *)name;`?  Would that follow the same pattern?

Comment: Additionally, how to I mark the function as `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` so I don't have to manage my memory manually?

Comment: Not quite the same, unfortunately. I've edited my answer to cover that and the `NS_RETURNS_RETAINED` question.

Comment: Thanks for following up, appreciate your incredible answer!