# How to invoke a class method using performSelector() on AnyClass in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, reflection, performselector, swift2

In ObjC you could simply invoke a class method using the class method from `NSObject`.

```c
[Machine performSelector:@selector(calculate:) withObject:num];
```

But how do you do this in Swift 2.2?

```
@objc(Machine) // put it here, so you can simply copy/paste into Playground
class Machine: NSObject {
    static func calculate(param: NSNumber) -> String {
        if param.integerValue > 5 {
            return "42"
        }
        return "42" // there is only 1 answer to all the questions :D
    }
}

if let aClass = NSClassFromString("Machine") {
    let sel = #selector(Machine.calculate(_:))
    let num = NSNumber(integer: 1337)
    let answer = aClass.performSelector(sel, withObject: num) // compiler error
    // let answer = aClass.calculate(num)                     // <-- this works
    print(answer)
}
```

With this code I'm getting the following compiler error:

> error: cannot invoke 'performSelector' with an argument list of type '(Selector, withObject: NSNumber)'

What am I missing here?

Comment: It is definitely not pointless,  what if you want to use the class from an external source?  E.G. reading the class name from a string in a plist,  are you going to write an if condition based on every possible object?

Comment: Related: [Access Private UIKit Function Without Using Bridging Header](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35183818/2415822)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`AnyClass` does not conform to `NSObjectProtocol` out of the box.  I had to cast `aClass` as `NSObjectProtocol` to use `performSelector` (`performSelector:withObject:` is bridged to Swift as a method on `NSObjectProtocol`):

Swift 3:

```
if let aClass = NSClassFromString("Machine") {
    let sel = #selector(Machine.calculate(param:))
    let num = NSNumber(value: 1337)

    if let myClass = aClass as? NSObjectProtocol {
        if myClass.responds(to: sel) {
            let answer = myClass.perform(sel, with: num).takeRetainedValue() // this returns AnyObject, you may want to downcast to your desired type
            print(answer) // "42\n"
        }
    }
}
```

Swift 2.x:

```
(aClass as! NSObjectProtocol).performSelector(sel, withObject: num) // Unmanaged<AnyObject>(_value: 42)
```

A little bit safer:

```
if let aClass = NSClassFromString("Machine") {
    let sel = #selector(Machine.calculate(_:))
    let num = NSNumber(integer: 1337)

    if let myClass = aClass as? NSObjectProtocol {
        if myClass.respondsToSelector(sel) {
            let answer = myClass.performSelector(sel, withObject: num).takeUnretainedValue()
            print(answer) // "42\n"
        }
    }
}
```

`performSelector` returns an `Unmanaged` object, that's why `takeUnretainedValue()` (or optionally `takeRetainedValue()` if you want to transfer memory ownership) are required.

Comment: That is funny, because casting it as? AnyObject worked for me

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Casting to `AnyObject` will work because `AnyClass` is really a typealias for the metatype `AnyObject.Type`.  You probably got a warning that the cast aways succeeds because they're the same type.  Probably not a good idea to cast a class to an object though.

Comment: @Knight0fDragon You can only use `performSelector` on Objective-C types, not pure Swift types.  Try it.  That's why I check for `NSObjectProtocol` conformance.

Comment: I have no warning on my screen, and wouldn't NSClassFromString automatically fail for swift types?

Comment: @Knight0fDragon Hmm, good point about `NSClassFromString`.  But I still see a warning if I try to cast the class as `AnyObject`: `if let myClass = aClass as? AnyObject { ... }`  I'm using Xcode 7.3.

Comment: yes, weird,  use my code and you won't see is,  maybe it is because it is AnyClass?   ?

Comment: ahh, I need to upgrade to 2.2 again,  seems like my install went bad, I will get back to you on the warning

Comment: thanks! I knew I was missing some conformance but didn't know which protocol and where to look it up ;)

Comment: Finally got swift 2.2 working again,  anyway,  yes, still not warning,  Also,  since we know that NSClass is going to return a member of NSClass when valid,  I do not think the second variable is needed, you can just check if aClass is a member of NSObjectProtocol, and see if it responds to the selector there

Comment: @Knight0fDragon yes, this code can probably be optimized further like `if let aClass = NSClassFromString("Machine") as? NSObjectProtocol { ... }` but I left the answer expanded so users can see the flow of casting from `AnyClass` to `NSObjectProtocol`.  I think it's easier to read like this and can always be optimized further as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: @Buju Yes forgot that earlier, so I wanted to make my code a little bit safer in case another user finds it and decides to use it.

Comment: "You can only use performSelector on Objective-C types, not pure Swift types." But actually, at runtime, pure Swift types *do* support `.respondsToSelector()`, `.performSelector()`, etc. So casting to `AnyObject` (to overcome lack of knowledge of such support at compile-time) and using them *does* work, without needing for the type to conform to `NSObjectProtocol`.

Comment: @newacct Ah you're right!  I actually just asked a question about this [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36851866/2415822).  Even though pure Swift classes are represented as `SwiftObject` to the Objective-C runtime, you need to explicitly declare your object as `AnyObject` or `NSObjectProtocol` to fire Objective-C selectors on it.

Comment: Oddly, Swift 4 will emit a warning trying to cast `AnyClass` to `NSObjectProtocol`, which annoys me. At runtime it still works, but trying to keep clean project of warnings. Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: @Legoless  use `if let myClass = aClass as AnyObject as? NSObjectProtocol {`

Answer (score -1):

If you want to perform calculate on machine, just do:

```
Machine.calculate(NSNumber(integer: 1337))
```

If you need to call perform selector, then do:

```
if let aClass = NSClassFromString("Machine") as? AnyObject
{
    let sel = #selector(Machine.calculate(_:))
    let num = NSNumber(integer: 1337)
    let answer = aClass.performSelector(sel, withObject: num)
    print(answer)
}
```