# Unrecognised selector invoking "_setApplicationIsOpaque:"

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, iphone-privateapi

I am trying to access the iOS private function `_setApplicationIsOpaque:` (just for personal use and test).

I have implemented this code:

```
@_silgen_name("_setApplicationIsOpaque:") func _setApplicationIsOpaque(_ arg1: Bool)

let invokeSetApplicationIsOpaque: (Bool) -> Void = {
    // The Objective-C selector for the method.
    let selector: Selector = Selector(("_setApplicationIsOpaque:"))
    guard case let method = class_getInstanceMethod(UIApplication.self, selector), method != nil else {
        fatalError("Failed to look up \(selector)")
    }

    // Recreation of the method's implementation function.
    typealias Prototype = @convention(c) (AnyClass, Selector, Bool) -> Void
    let opaqueIMP = method_getImplementation(method)
    let function = unsafeBitCast(opaqueIMP, to: Prototype.self)

    // Capture the implemenation data in a closure that can be invoked at any time.
    return{ arg1 in function(UIApplication.self, selector, arg1)}
}()

extension UIApplication {
    func setApplicationIsOpaque(_ isOpaque: Bool) {
        return invokeSetApplicationIsOpaque(isOpaque)
    }
}
```

I found this way to access private iOS API in the following StackOverflow question [Access Private UIKit Function Without Using Bridging Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35183818/access-private-uikit-function-without-using-bridging-header)
and in [this file](https://github.com/bogren/DeviceColor/blob/master/DeviceColor/UIDevice%2BDeviceColor.swift) on GitHub.

The problem is that running the app I get the error

> [UIApplication _setBackgroundStyle:]: unrecognized selector sent to class 0x10437f348

I have found the header of iOS private APIs of UIApplication [in this GitHub repository](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/blob/master/Frameworks/UIKit.framework/UIApplication.h).

Comment: Sorry if I have made some mistakes with the language, I'm Italian.

Comment: SPOLIER: I can't make the app background transparent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
- (void)_setApplicationIsOpaque:(BOOL)arg1;
```

is an *instance* method (of `UIApplication`), as indicated by
the initial hyphen `-`. Instance methods are sent to an instance
of the class, not to the class itself.

Objective-C methods are C functions with two hidden arguments, compare
[Messaging](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtHowMessagingWorks.html)
in the "Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide":

> It also passes the procedure two hidden arguments:
>
> - The receiving object
> - The selector for the method

For instance methods, the "receiving object" is the instance to
which the message is sent, in your case the `UIApplication` instance.
(For *class methods* it would be the class object).

Therefore the Swift extension method `setApplicationIsOpaque`
must pass `self` to the closure, and that must be passed as
the first argument to the implementation method:

```
let invokeSetApplicationIsOpaque: (UIApplication, Bool) -> Void = {
    // The Objective-C selector for the method.
    let selector = Selector(("_setApplicationIsOpaque:"))
    guard case let method = class_getInstanceMethod(UIApplication.self, selector), method != nil else {
        fatalError("Failed to look up \(selector)")
    }
    
    // Recreation of the method's implementation function.
    typealias Prototype = @convention(c) (UIApplication, Selector, Bool) -> Void
    let opaqueIMP = method_getImplementation(method)
    let function = unsafeBitCast(opaqueIMP, to: Prototype.self)
    
    // Capture the implemenation data in a closure that can be invoked at any time.
    return { (appl, arg1) in function(appl, selector, arg1)}
}()

extension UIApplication {
    func setApplicationIsOpaque(_ isOpaque: Bool) {
        return invokeSetApplicationIsOpaque(self, isOpaque)
    }
}
```

---

Note that the `_silgen_name` declaration is not needed here.

```
@_silgen_name("_setApplicationIsOpaque:") func _setApplicationIsOpaque(_ arg1: Bool)
```

binds the Swift function to a global symbol "_setApplicationIsOpaque",
which does not exist. If you would add a call to that function

```
_setApplicationIsOpaque(true)
```

then building the app would fail with a linker error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:  "__setApplicationIsOpaque:"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it works! But can you explain better why I don't need `_silgen_name` and why I have to pass also the instance while in the second link I have posted it doesn't pass the UIDevice instance, please?

Comment: @ale00: _silgen_name binds a Swift function to a global function, as in the last code example in http://stackoverflow.com/a/35231921/1187415, it does not bind to class or instance methods (as also mentioned in that answer). – An Objective-C method is a C function with takes two "implicit parameters": the receiver and the selector (compare e.g. https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtDynamicResolution.html). For an instance method, the receiver is the instance.

Comment: @MartinR Nice question there :)